# How to pass different arguments to view

Tags: views, entities, users

I am using profile2 field as user reference and also i filter results with an entity selection. The widget used is an autocomplete and i have a problem with it. If i type in the nid of a user the result returned is correct, but it does not work if i type in the name of the user or anything else related to it besides nid.

Example:

- for this url everything is fine ( returns the name of profile with nid == 1):

  ```
  entityreference/autocomplete/single/field_test/profile2/profiletype/NULL/1
  ```
- but if i type "name" the result is null

  ```
    entityreference/autocomplete/single/field_test/profile2/profiletype/NULL/name
  ```

Is there any configuration that i miss ? Is it possible to change the behavior of autocomplete ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to modify the views query!